# How web applications reject wildcard in cookie's domain

Tags: validation, web, cookies

While bug hunting, I found a website that sets its session cookie's domain like sub1.mydomain.com.
But I also found an XSS in sub2.sub1.mydomain.com that allows me to create that session cookie with domain .sub1.mydomain.com (leading dot) and the application accepted the cookie as valid.

I understand that on client's side, there is nothing that can be done, browsers will accept the second cookie as valid.
The question is how web applications could reject the second cookie server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that they can't know where the cookie was from. That's one reason why `__HOST`-prefixed cookies exist: if you name your cookie that, you can distinguish it from a cookie that was inherited from a different origin.

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/cookie-prefixes/

Comment: But that doesn't protect from the case where the cookie is set by an XSS vulnerability. The XSS can set the cookie name the way it needs to be. I was looking for some protection on the backend that checks if the domain of the cookie is what it should be (for example, not allowing the leading dot)

Comment: Cookie behavior is subtle, so your confusion is understandable. The __HOST feature exists for exactly the XSS scenario. 

Critical to understand is that when the browser sends a cookie to a server, it doesn't send any info about which |domain| string it was set. So the backend cannot "check" the domain of the cookie.

However, if a cookie's name starts with `__HOST`, the server **knows** that cookie was set for the exact origin receiving it-- no domain rule can be specified that would send the cookie to a subdomain or a parent domain, because the browser would refuse to set the cookie.